# How to fix firebase notification icon in background it is not showing on background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added  firebase notification in my app . When app is running i get notification icon but when my app is in background or closed than notification icon doesn't show . Eiher it is small icon or large .

i have done many solution from Stackoverflow but all failed.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)

            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)

            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorGivelife))
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.logo))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.white_logo);
        builder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGivelife));
    } else {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    }
```

I can get notification icon when app is in background.

Answer (score 3):

Use this tag and put it in your Manifest. For me this worked. Hope it works for you.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_app_icon" />
```

Comment: <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/logo" /> <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorGivelife" />

Comment: i have added this but failed

Comment: Make sure your logo should be 72*72 pixels. @ŠhøñűMøňů

Comment: yes i know..my logo is 72*72..when app is running icon shows perfectly....but when in background icon not show

Comment: can you share the dependency  you are using?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'

Comment: Do you  using transparent png ?

Comment: I asked for transparent png . Means Background will be transparent .

Comment: plz help me @Muntasir

Comment: I am checking give me 5 min

Comment: but i cant understand that?